# Restart a program of child process in C++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, process

I have learned recently about processes and threads, and I am building a project where I need to run a program inside a child process.
The problem is that after the program in the child process exits I don't know how to restart and run the program again.

Here's a test which demonstrates what I am trying to do.

main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include "handler.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "usage: program name" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, nullptr, nullptr) < 0)
            std::cerr << "ptrace error" << std::endl;
        else
            execl(argv[1], argv[1], nullptr); 
    }
    else if (pid >= 1)
    {
        Handler handler(std::string(argv[1]), pid);
        handler.run();
    }
}
```

handler.h file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

class Handler
{

private:
    pid_t m_pid;
    std::string m_name;
public:
    Handler(const std::string& name, pid_t pid) : m_name(name), m_pid(pid)
    {
    }

    void run()
    {
        std::string line;
        while (true)
        {   
            std::cout << "(command) ";
            std::getline(std::cin, line);

            if (line == "run")
            {
                int options = 0, status = 0;
                ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, m_pid, nullptr, nullptr);
                int pid = waitpid(m_pid, &status, options);

                // trying to restart again the program
                if (pid < 0)
                {
                    m_pid = fork();
                    execl(m_name.c_str(), m_name.c_str(), nullptr);
                }

            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why allow the peer process (or thread) to stop?  What is your motivation to "restart"?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN , here is just a test to demonstrate the problem. In my project, I run a program in child process, and get details about it using ptrace. So, I want that when the program exits, to be able to start it again.

Comment: Carefully reread what the manual page says about the return value from `waitpid`, now look at what your code does with this, and ask yourself the following question: "does that make sense?"